# How to insert a row in an HTML table without id in JavaScript

Tags: html, node.js, dom, simple-html-dom

I have an HTML table on any site:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>customer</td>
        <td class="ltr" id="e6">2</td>
        <td class="ltr" id="e9">2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to do some calculation and return a number with my written chrome extension with this code:

```
    var tradeActBox = document.createElement('tr');
    var before = document.getElementById('e9');
    tradeActBox.innerHTML =
        '<td>power</td><td>buy</td><td>sell</td>';
    insertAfter(tradeActBox, before);
}

function insertAfter(el, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(el, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}
```

but problem is previous tr tag not closing and make collession like this :

```
<tr>
<td>customer</td>
<td class="ltr highlight1" id="e6">2</td>
<td class="ltr highlight1" id="e9">2</td>
<tr>
    <td>power</td>
    <td>buy</td>
    <td>sell</td>
</tr>
```

I want to make row like this code :

```
    <tr>
    <td>customer</td>
    <td class="ltr highlight1" id="e6">2</td>
    <td class="ltr highlight1" id="e9">2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>power</td>
    <td>buy</td>
    <td>sell</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following modified version of `insertAfter()`:

```js
function insertAfter(el, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', el);
}
```

Here we use `insertAdjacentElement()` to insert the new table row after the end of the first row, which would be after the closing `</tr>` tag.

More information can be found here: [Element.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)